# Как вставить список данных в MSSQL без дубликатов строк используя JPA?

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

Уже третий день не могу решить задачу. Была база Оракл, и система с ней работала. Теперь нужно все перевести на  MSSQL. И вот в старой реализации использовали голые  sql запросы а сейчас я прикрутил  hibernate jpa. И вот есть такой запрос в оракл, который запрещает создавать дубликаты строк при insert'e

```
insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(table_m=name, index_name) */  into
```

И он работает правильно. Я стал копать подобное в  MSSQL и нашел единственное это

```
create unique index IX_TableName_IndexName on TableName (KeyColumn1, KeyColumn2, ...)
    with (ignore_dup_key = on)
```

Это посоветовали на этом сайте. Я Создал индекс. И при insert'е через  SQL managment studio голым запросом первая строка вставляется, а ее дубликат нет. Выходит предупреждение, что это дубликат. Вроде бы все то что и нужно.

Но при вставке дублирующей строки из  Java с использованием JPA мне возвращается ошибка

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException
```

после чего вызывается rollback и вся моя транзакция отменяется.

Я искал способы пропустить ошибки hibernate jpa или варнинги хотябы, но не нашел. Других способов избежать вставки дублирующих строк тоже не нашел. Ни средствами  SQL  ни средствами самой ОРМ.

Решил insert'ить по одной строке. Пусть медленней но rollback отменит мне только ненужную строку и все. Но на практике сейчас снова ошибка:

```
Transaction not active
```

Вот мой метод для insert'а массива данных:

```
public void insertAVAYAcmCDRs(List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (AvayaCmCdr aCdrList : cdrList) {
            try {
                em.persist(aCdrList);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Exception in  task time={0}. Exception message = {1}.", new Object[]{aCdrList.getDate(), e.getMessage()});
            }
            try {
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Exception in  task time={0}. Exception message = {1}.", new Object[]{new Date(), e.getMessage()});
            }
        }
        em.clear();
    }
```

Обернул все в `try...catch` чтобы выловить ошибку, и вот выловил, но незнаю что и как делать.

Кто сталкивался или время есть разобраться, помогите решить проблему. По факту нужно из Java  сделать  insert  диста данных в  MSSQL таким образом чтобы туда попали только уникальные строки и не дублировались. И все это через  JPA

Comment: Вероятно в Вашем приложении на самом деле используется JTA, а не Local Transaction? Для участия в JTA надо вызывать `em.joinTransaction()` (или что-то в этом роде. точно не скажу в каком классе JPA этот join) при ручном управление транзакциями. А вообще перед добавлением новой записи проверяли бы сначала - а не является ли она дубликатом. Или кто-то в это время параллельно  занимается удалением недавно добавленных записей?

Comment: нет не удаляет пока никто ничего параллельно. просто объемы данных огромные

Comment: Что быстрее: запуск+коммит транзакции или проверка, что запись уже имеется. Да и кроме того всегда можно от JPA получить доступ к JDBC, которую он сам использует, и выполнить все insert-ы через этот JDBC